# Adding items to a list with out overwriting the previous item

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, list

I am trying to send form data to a confirmation page where you would enter your cc info to complete the transaction. I add all the information to a list that i will later code as hidden fields on the new form to send the information off as paid. However when I do a repsonse.write to see what the information stored is.  i always get the same name over and over.  not exactly sure where i am missing it.  Thanks for your help!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST"){
        formData attendee = new formData();
        NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
        List<formData> attendees = new List<formData>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["fn1"]))
        {
            var fn = nvc["fn1"];
            var ln = nvc["ln1"];
            var email = nvc["email1"];
            var wife = nvc["wife1"];
            var luncheon = nvc["lucheon1"];

            attendee.firstName = fn; attendee.lastName = ln; attendee.email = email; attendee.wife = wife; attendee.luncheon = luncheon;
            attendees.Add(attendee);

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["fn2"]))
        {
            var fn = nvc["fn2"];
            var ln = nvc["ln2"];
            var email = nvc["email2"];
            var wife = nvc["wife2"];
            var luncheon = nvc["lucheon2"];

            attendee.firstName = fn; attendee.lastName = ln; attendee.email = email; attendee.wife = wife; attendee.luncheon = luncheon;
            attendees.Add(attendee);
        }

        foreach(var person in attendees)
        {
            Response.Write(person.firstName.ToString());
            Response.Write(person.lastName.ToString());
            Response.Write(person.email.ToString());
            Response.Write(person.wife.ToString());
            Response.Write(person.luncheon.ToString());
        }
    }
}
public class formData
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string wife { get; set; }
    public string luncheon { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: Might because you are re-creating the attendees list everytime the page loads?

Comment: That's what i was thinking, should the page load function only call the function once?

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your array of Attendees is going to be of a data type like this... each attendee has a {fn, ln, email, wife, and luncheon} property. Looks like they're stored in the POST like {fn1, ln1, email1, wife1, luncheon1} is attendee(0), {fn2, ln2, email2, wife2, luncheon2} is attendee(1), etc.

You might try looping like this

```
var count = 1;
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["fn" + count]))
{
    attendee(count).firstname=nvc["fn" + count]
    attendee(count).lastname=nvc["ln" + count]
    //...for the rest of the fields
    count++; //be sure and increment count
}
```

Until there's data fn# that is null, it keeps looping through and creating attendees.

Comment: its giving me an error when i try to use attendee(count).  do i need to switch my list over to an array?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the list in the Page_Load event. The Page_Load event fires each time the page loads, postback or not and recreating the list every time that event fires.

You can create and use a session variable. As an example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<formData> attendees;

    if(Session["attendees"] == null)
    {
        attendees = new List<formData>();
        // your logic logic ...
        Session["attendees"] = attendees;
    }
    else
    {
        var attendees = (List<formData>)Session["attendees"];
        // your logic ...
        Session["attendees"] = attendees;
    }
}
```

I'd also consider breaking your code out a bit. Perhaps putting the code that adds to the list in a separate method.

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks,  This page is the landing page after you enter the people you are paying for to attend a conference, and will be used to collect CC information and store all the names to the database as paid. so this would be once per session.   I am sure there is a simpler way to go about doing this but i am still fairly new to asp.net.

Comment: Then you can use a session variable.